# Unable to set cookie using CO flag in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cookies, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I am trying to set cookie using CO rewrite flag by following this doc

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co

My cookie value contains `:` So I am using `;` to separate cookie attributes as suggested in the documentation but the response cookie is not setting.

```
RewriteRule .* - [CO=;name;value1:value2;.example.com;43200;/]
```

if I use first method from doc it works but not sufficient for my use case,

```
RewriteRule .* - [CO=name:value1:.example.com:43200:/]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does using the second version, and URL-encoding the colon as `%3A`, work?

Comment: @CBore Tried that and not receiving full encoded value in cookie value,   Example: `RewriteRule .* - [CO=testname:value%3Atest:.example.com:43200:/]`  returned cookie value as  `valueAtest`

Comment: @Pakora You would need to backslash-escape the `%`, otherwise this will be seen as an "empty" backreference (to a non-existent `RewriteCond` directive). ie. `CO=testname:value\%3Atest`. (Although I'm not sure that URL-encoding is really the correct thing to do here (it's not a URL) - it's no better than replacing `:` with another character and converting it back when read in.)

Comment: @MrWhite @CBroe this is really helpful, Now I can see value `value%3Atest` in cookie, which works for my use case . Thank you!

Comment: @MrWhite regarding URL-encoding, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes says, _"Encoding: Many implementations perform URL encoding on cookie values. However, this is not required by the RFC specification. The URL encoding does help to satisfy the requirements of the characters allowed for `<cookie-value>`."_ - so I guess this should work reasonably well.

Comment: It also says there, _"A `<cookie-value>` can optionally be wrapped in double quotes and include any US-ASCII character excluding a control character, Whitespace, double quotes, comma, semicolon, and backslash."_ - so that could also be an alternative here.